# sympy piecewise:i want to use array loop

Tags: python, sympy

sympy piecewise:i want use array loop

OK

```
from sympy import *
var('x')
myP1 = (0, x < -1)
myP2 = (x, x <= 1)
myP3 = (1, x >= 5)
myPw1= Piecewise(  myP1,myP2,myP3 )
myPw2= Piecewise(*(myP1,myP2,myP3))
print("#",myPw1,myPw1.subs(x,6))
print("#",myPw2,myPw2.subs(x,6))
# Piecewise((0, x < -1), (x, x <= 1), (1, x >= 5)) 1
# Piecewise((0, x < -1), (x, x <= 1), (1, x >= 5)) 1
```

i want use array. (i want use Sum or use Append)

i want use array loop

TypeError

```
from sympy import *
var('x myP')
myP[1] = (0, x < -1)
myP[2] = (x, x <= 1)
myP[3] = (1, x >= 5)
myPw   = Piecewise(*(myP[1] , myP[2] , myP[3]))
print("#",myPw,myPw.subs(x,6))
#     myP[1] = (0, x < -1)
# TypeError: 'Symbol' object does not support item assignment
```

(2022-03-11)

i try tuple

```
from sympy import *
var('x')
myP=[]
myP=myP+list([(0, x < -1)])
myP=myP+list([(x, x <= 1)])
myP=myP+list([(1, x >= 5)])
myPw=Piecewise(*myP)
print("#",myPw)
myP=[]
myP=list([(0, x < -1)])+list([(x, x <= 1)])+list([(1, x >= 5)])
myPw=Piecewise(*myP)
print("#",myPw)
# Piecewise((0, x < -1), (x, x <= 1), (1, x >= 5))
# Piecewise((0, x < -1), (x, x <= 1), (1, x >= 5))
```

Answer (score 1):

You created symbols `x` and `myP` and then you tried to treat `myP` like a list (or something indexable) by writing `myP[1] = ...`. Instead, create a list and assign/append values:

```
>>> myP = []
>>> myP.append((0, x < -1))
>>> myP.append((x, x <= 1))
>>> myP.append((1, x >= 5))
>>> myPw = Piecewise(*myP)
```